# Use fs promise to move a file

Tags: node.js, buffer, fs

I have a nodeJS app server-side that receives files.

The user sends a file from the client and I want to make several operations, one of them being moving the file to the final destination. I used to use `file.mv`, but I need to make my functions async; I saw that `mv` didn't exist in fsPromises and it seems `fsPromises.rename` would do the trick: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fspromisesrenameoldpath-newpath

`Buffer` seems to be a valid argument type, but when I write

```
await fsPromises.rename(file, newDir)
```

I have this error:

```
"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"rename","path":"FILE NAME.txt","dest":"XXX"}
```

(`XXX` has been created successfully the step before)

Here is what `console.log(file)` shows:

```
{"name":"FILE NAME.txt","data":{"type":"Buffer","data":[XX,XX,XX,XX,XX...]},"size":60,"encoding":"7bit","tempFilePath":"","truncated":false,"mimetype":"text/plain","md5":"cfd5514321a15034355f895e52d69fac"}
```

I supposed I had to use the data:

```
await fsPromises.rename(file.data.data, newDir)
```

But I have another error:

```
"code":"ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE"
```

I finally tried with `file.name` only, but again, I receive an error:

```
"errno":-2,"code":"ENOENT","syscall":"rename","path":"FILE NAME.txt","dest":"XXX"}
```

I tried to create a buffer:

```
let buf = Buffer.from(file.data);
  await fsPromises.rename(buf, newDir)
```

But I have an error because Node thinks I'm sending the path as argument, whereas it's a buffer created from file data.

What would be the correct way to replace my former use of:

```
file.mv(newDir, async function(err)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is `mv`? - I don't think it's part of Node, and I see something remarkably like it as an (old) 3rd party module https://github.com/andrewrk/node-mv.  Per the comments all this does if a rename fails is to pipe the contents from the first arg to the second. This is done here: https://github.com/andrewrk/node-mv/blob/master/index.js#L58 and is async and uses the (callback) streaming API.

Answer (score -1):

Method `fsPromises.rename(oldPath, newPath)` needs the paths as arguments and not file content buffers. Example usage:

```js
await fsPromises.rename('old/name.txt', 'new/name.txt');
```